# masm assembly unresolved externals

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

My class is working out of the "Assembly programming for Intel computers" book (5th edition) and I'm trying to get the programs to assemble. The book comes with Irvine32.inc which is supposed to make IO and stuff easier. I have those in the same directory as the .asm file I'm trying to compile. Whenever I do ml /Fe test.exe test.asm /link I always get errors about every function from that library I am included saying "unresolved external" like:

test.obj(test.asm): error Lsomething : '_READINT@0' : unresolved external

I know the program works because it is working on my friend's computer (I'm on 64bit linux running this through dosemu also). And of course I have:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
```

in my source. Anyway the program will compile but it will instantly kill dosemu and not show me why. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Great, great great great book. Irvine 5th edition? heh

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not specify the library to /link with (i.e. check your command line).